# Two Digit Pointer? How did this happen?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, free

So on a project I'm working on I'm getting the following error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./social_network: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x09a913b0 ***
```

A few printf statements revealed the the struct I'm freeing that causes this error has a memory address of....17. So how is this possible? What could have happened to make this appear...?

Here's some output right before the crash:

```
temp is: 162075592
temp user is  162075408
After free of temp
inside while loop, first line
before free of temp
temp is: 162075760
temp user is  162075480
After free of temp
inside while loop, first line
before free of temp
temp is: 162075568
temp user is  17
```

And here's the code that outputs the output

```
 21 void destroy() {
 22 
 23     struct user_node *node;
 24 
 25     struct friend_node *temp;
 26     struct friend_node *next_temp;
 27     
 28     //iterate over the list of users
 29     while (*head != NULL) {
 30         printf("before a_friend\n");
 31         temp = (*head)->a_friend;
 32         
 33         //Iterate over friends of users, free friend nodes
 34         while (temp != NULL) {
 35             printf("inside while loop, first line\n");
 36             next_temp = temp->next_friend;
 37             printf("before free of temp\n");
 38             printf("temp is: %d\n", (int) temp);
 39             printf("temp user is  %d\n", (int)temp->user);
 40             free(temp); <==================================SEGFAULT IS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 41             printf("After free of temp\n");
 42             temp = next_temp;
 43             next_temp = NULL;
 44         }
 45 
 46         node = (*head)->next_user;
 47         printf("before free of: %s\n", (*head)->name);
 48         free(*head);
 49         printf("after free of that person...\n");
 50         *head = node;
 51         printf("*head = node afterwards\n");
 52         node = NULL;
 53     }
 54     printf("before final free...\n");
 55     free(head);
 56 }
```

EDIT:

struct friend_node

```
 23 //node used to store a pointer to a user_node and next friend
 24 struct friend_node {
 25     struct friend_node *next_friend;
 26     struct user_node *user;
 27 };
```

struct user_node

```
 12 //Struct definitions
 13 //node used to store information about a user
 14 struct user_node {
 15     char name[21];
 16     int age;
 17     int gender;
 18     char location[21];
 19     struct friend_node *a_friend;
 20     struct user_node *next_user;
 21 };
 22
```

Comment: Will you please give the definition of `struct friend_node`?

Comment: sure thing, added the struct friend_node as well as struct user_node definitions above

Comment: If you have user A, B, C - C is a friend of both A & B. When creating lists of friends for User A & User B, do you create separate friend wrappers for C for A & B or do you reuse the same friend wrapper at both places?

Comment: yes, different friend wrappers are used.

Comment: @Ethan side note : when you're printing a pointer, use "%p". Otherwise you're assuming a pointer fits an `int`.

Comment: Where is `head` defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in your code that would suggest that you are freeing a struct at address `17`, as you seem to incorrectly believe.

Both the crash message and your dump clearly show that you are attempting to free pointer `temp` that points to address `162075568` (`0x09a913b0`). That pointer points to invalid memory, which is why `free` crashes. This is also why you might see `17` stored inside that memory. That memory is invalid, so there's nothing surprising in the fact that it stores random garbage.

Forget about that `17`. It has nothing to do with anything. You problem is `162075568` (`0x09a913b0`). This value is invalid and that is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 7):

This usually happens when you are working with a NULL pointer. You see, when you access a struct's member, its offset is added to the pointer and then dereferenced:

```
somestruct *p = NULL;
printf("%d", p->member);
```

If the member is at offset e.g. 0xC, then you will not receive an error like "trying to access memory at 0x0", but "trying to access memory at 0xC".

**EDIT**: As others suggested, this is probably not the cause of your problem. But it's one common reason to receive an error at a "two-digit pointer".

Comment: If `p` would equal `NULL` `free(p)` shall not cause a segmentation violation, as per the standard `free(NULL)` is valid.

Comment: AndreyT: I am talking about the error message (segfault) you will get with the code, not the value that gets printed. You *will* receive an error about accessing memory at 0xC.

Comment: @AndreyT How exactly would the value being passed to `printf()` by offsetting against a structure pointer *not* be utilizing the address in said-pointer to get the value? In the above sample a fault *will* happen due to memory access at NULL+(offset of member). It won't happen in the printf(); it will happen in *this* calling code.

Comment: @alk `free(NULL)` is certainly defined behavior. `temp = ((struct node *)(NULL))->next_node` prior to that free is certainly not, which I believe is kuba's point. That is effectively what you get with member-var access through a NULL pointer, and almost always reports as an access error at location "0+offsetofmember" in the crash log.

Comment: @WhozCraig: OK, fair enough. But in that case I don't see the relevance. Firstly, we know the pointer is not null. Secondly, there was no crash trying to access the field (i.e. the garbage value of `17` was successfully read). I.e. we are not dealing will offseted null here (at least not immediately).

Comment: @AndreyT I concur on all points made last-comment. Somehow he managed to stuff 0x17 into a `friend_node.user` pointer. Without seeing more code on how he *builds* and *maintains* the friends lists, I'm kinda doubting the absolute bottom of this fault will be trivially apparent.

Answer (score 2):

> What could have happened to make this appear

There are many kinds of undefined behavior. Buffer overruns, accesses to deallocated objects, uninitialized variables all come to mind.

In hunting these things down,`valgrind` is your best friend. Use it early and often.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to initalise all `struct` members being pointers to `NULL` on creation/allocation of the `struct`.